# Is this a typo or a delicate point to understand?

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ is a discrete random variable with distribution $F(t) = P(X \leq t)$. We know $P(X < t) = \lim_{s \to t^-} F(t) $. In trying to find a probability like $P(1/2 < X < 3/2) $, I would do

$$ P(X<3/2) - P(X<1/2) = \lim_{x \to 3/2^-} F(t) - \lim_{x \to 1/2^- } F(t) $$

However, professor wrote

$$ P(1/2 < X < 3/2) = P(X<3/2)  -  P(X \leq 1/2)  = P(X<3/2) - F(1/2) $$

is this a typo? or I am misunderstanding the concept?

Comment: We have $$\{X<3/2\} = \{X\leq 1/2\} \cup \{1/2<X<3/2\}$$ where the right-hand-side is a union of disjoint events, and so $$P[X<3/2] = P[X\leq 1/2] + P[1/2<X<3/2]$$

Comment: Note that $P[a < X \le b] = F(b)-F(a)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a typo.

The notation $(1/2 < X < 3/2)$ is just a convenient notation for the event (=set) $\{ X \in (1/2,3/2)\; \}$. In particular, since the interval $(1/2,3/2)$ can be expressed as $A\setminus B$, where $A=(-\infty, 3/2)$ and $B=(-\infty, 1/2]$ (note the square bracket at the end), we have

$$P(1/2 < X < 3/2) = P(A\setminus B) = P(X<3/2) - P(X\leqslant 1/2)$$

By definition, the last term is $P(X\leqslant 1/2)=F(1/2)$.

---

In other words, being strictly between $1/2$ and $3/2$ (that is, $1/2<X<3/2$) means being smaller than $3/2$ (that is, $X<3/2$) but not smaller than **or equal to** $1/2$ (that is, $X \leqslant 1/2$).

If $X=1/2$, then $X$ does not satisfy $1/2 < X < 3/2$.

Answer (score 3):

Your professor's answer is correct

Remember that you are dealing with a **discrete** random variable, so you can't just assume that the probability of being exactly $1/2$ is zero, so you need to remember to subtract it off.

Your solution finds $P(1/2 \le X \lt 3/2)$ which isnt necessarily the same for discrete random variables